# Webbrowser plugin for OSMC

Tags: raspbian

I searched a lot but didn't find one.

How do I add a normal Webbrower like Firefox or Chrome into my OSMC?

I managed to install the [Superrepo](https://superrepo.org), but I cannot find any add-on that sounds like a web browser in those either.

Comment: I tried superrepo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMC announces development of its official browser Ocelot at https://osmc.tv/2015/05/osmc-release-candidate-3-lands/22

> As promised before, OSMC will bring a web browser to all supported devices. This will be hardware accelerated and should perform well on all devices (whether it’s the single core Pi 1 or our later planned for x64 release). We’re naming it Ocelot and it should arrive in September

Comment: Ocelot development seems to have stalled.

Comment: stalled, but one day it will be finished ;)

Comment: - Ocelot status? Is development stalled?
So, nobody's able to create some sort of wrapper to existing browser, and have that shown if need be ... :P !? They insist on creating a browser from scratch? (and fails?)

Comment: The link is dead